# why the text-field always return null?

Tags: java, html, database, servlets

The following snippet submits a caption to the database. After filling in the text , i click submit but to my surprise always a *null* goes to the table. I have metioned the servlet code and the html design below:

```
<form method="post" action="Handler" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td> <strong> Leave a caption </strong>  </td>
                <td> <input type="text" name="caption box" size="40" /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr colspan="2">
                <td> <input type="submit" value="submit caption"/> </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
```

**Servlet**

```
String caption = request.getParameter("caption box"); // get the caption from the caption field
HandleCaption hc = new HandleCaption(caption,emailOfTheUser,fileName);
hc.SubmitCaptionToTheDatabase();
```

**Class**

```
public class HandleCaption {
private String Caption = null;
private String UserEmail = null;
private String NameOfThe = null;

public HandleCaption(String caption,String email,String filename) {
    Caption = caption;
    UserEmail = email;
    NameOfThe = filename;
}

public void SubmitCaptionToTheDatabase() {
    try {
        Context context = new InitialContext();
        DataSource ds = (DataSource)context.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/DS");
        Connection connection = ds.getConnection();
        String sqlQuery = "insert into CAPTIONS values ('" + UserEmail + "','" + NameOfThe + "','" + Caption + "')";
        PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sqlQuery);
        int x = statement.executeUpdate();
    }catch(Exception exc) {
        exc.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

I tried printing the value the text-field returned in the servlet which even the printed null. Why the text-field returns null ?

Comment: also i am unable to give space between the words in that text-field !

Comment: What's the result if you `input` widget doesn't use a name that contains a space?

Comment: do you really need multipart/form-data?

Comment: @GregKopff i didn't understand you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>i'm not sure why this happens but has happened to me once or twice..
i your Caption class Handle Caption, declare it as</strike>

```
private String Caption = "";
private String UserEmail = "";
private String NameOfThe = "";
```

i know it looks like a dumb answer to the question as in constructor you are actually referring to the value that is passed but i have experienced this and thats the solution for me.please try and reply!!

**Update:** sorry for adressing the question wrongly
its due to encoding type, will read about why its happening.. but just remove encoding type and it works..tried on sample code

**Update :** multipart/form-data encoded requests are indeed not by default supported by the Servlet API prior to version 3.0. The Servlet API parses the parameters by default using application/x-www-form-urlencoded encoding. When using a different encoding, the request.getParameter() calls will all return null.

Comment: read the question. I told that the vaule is null before i send it to helper class

Comment: its Due to Enctype.. i still have to find the reason but i made a sample code.. you repove the encoding type from the form tag and it works..i copy pasted your code and made a sample program

Comment: yes now it works! But i have to use _multipart encoding_. Is there a way out ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-in-jsp-servlet/2424824#2424824
please refer to article. for fetching the value using this encoding
you will need to add commons-fileupload.jar. the question has a beautiful answer.. please see to it

Comment: and if possible than please + the answer..!!

Comment: I did it that is the reason you are having 1 from -1

Answer (score 1):

Your name `captionbox` of field shouldn't contain space.

```
<input type="text" name="captionbox" size="40" />
```

remove spaces from it and also from servlet side.

Comment: I dont think it is a problem ,will u pls elobarate?

Comment: WHAT ! and why do you think that ?

Comment: And that's also the [W3C recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-cdata): "`ID` and `NAME` tokens must begin with a letter (`[A-Za-z]`) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits (`[0-9]`), hyphens (`"-"`), underscores (`"_"`), colons (`":"`), and periods (`"."`)."

Comment: Can you make sure that you are receiving the captain in servlet. try to print out it. also try to print the query which is being built before submitting it to database.

Comment: I wrote in my question that it reurns null

Comment: @Balaswamy: try not to use space and . in request variable.

Comment: @grassPro in accordance with my earlier comment, I am afraid you have just changed the request variable name from `caption box` to `captionbox` in your html but not in your servlet. I don't see any reason why you will get `null`  provided your request variable should not have <space> and <period> .

Comment: @Rakesh Juyal I changed in servlet too, but the same thing. NULL

Comment: ALSO I AM UNABLE TO USE SPACEBAR IN THAT TEXT FIELD. I AM WORKING ON SOMEBODY'S ELSE DESIGN, WHO HAS USED LOTS OF JQUERY AND JAVASCRRIPT. WHEN I TAP FOR SPACE,INSTEAD THE PHOTOS ON THE PAGE MOVE FURTHER !